# RxJava2 Flowable : send objects to server on by one and detect end

Tags: android, rx-java2

I need to send a list of objects to my remote server. As they may be numerous and big I use a flowable to send them one by one from an arraylist using request(1).

For each object a retrofit call is made to the server and in return I get the remote ID and I update the local object with the remote id.

I need to detect the end of this task : ie the last response for the last object sent to prevent multiple concurent calls for the same objects.

For the moment all works well but I get the "completed" message before the answer arrives from the remote server so before the object is updated.

How can I do this ?

```
Flowable<Integer> observable = Flowable.range(0, objList.size());

        observable.subscribe(new DefaultSubscriber<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d(TAG, "on start");
                request(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "on next : " + t);
                MyObj = objList.get(t);

                RetrofitHelper.createService(ObjService.class, true, authType, authToken).createOrUpdateObj(objList.get(t)).flatMap(p -> {

                    Log.d(TAG, "recu p");

                    if (p != null) {
                        try {
                            p.setSyncho(true);
                            // save remote id on obj
                            ObjDB.updateObj(p);
                            request(1);

                            return Observable.empty();
                        } catch (Throwable th) {
                            ExceptionHandler.logException(th);
                            return Observable.error(th);
                        }
                    } else {
                        request(1);
                        return Observable.empty();  // provisoirement si pb on renvoie vide
                    }
                })
                        .onErrorResumeNext(r -> {
                            request(1);
                            Observable.empty();
                        })
                        .onExceptionResumeNext(error -> Observable.empty()) // go to next on error
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).onErrorReturn(error -> {
                    Log.d("ERROR", error.getMessage());
                    return 0;
                })

                        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()).subscribe();
            }


            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                Log.e("XXX ERROR ", "" + t);
                request(1);
                patientSynchroInProgress = Boolean.FALSE;
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.e("XXX COMPLETE", "complete");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to get it work

```
  Flowable.fromIterable(patientList)
                    .concatMap(item -> {

                                item.setSomething();
                                return RetrofitHelper.createService(ObjService.class, true, authType, authToken)
                                        .createOrUpdateObj(item)
                                        .flatMap(p -> {
                                            if (p != null) {
                                                try {
                                                    p.setSyncho(true);
                                                    // save remote id on obj
                                                    ObjDB.updateObj(p);
                                                    return Observable.empty();
                                                } catch (Throwable th) {
                                                    ExceptionHandler.logException(th);
                                                    return Observable.error(th);
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                return Observable.empty();  // provisoirement si pb on renvoie vide
                                            }
                                        })

                                        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                                        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
                            }
                    )
                    .doOnNext(s -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, ((Obj) s).toString());

                    })
                    .doOnComplete(() -> {
                        // do something when completed
                        Log.d(TAG, "COMPLETE");
                    })
                    .subscribe();
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should move your retrofit call inside a `map(...)` operator:

```
Flowable<Integer> observable = Flowable.range(0, objList.size());

observable
     .map(t -> {
            MyObj = objList.get(t);

            return RetrofitHelper.createService(ObjService.class, true, authType, authToken).createOrUpdateObj(objList.get(t)).flatMap(p -> {

                    Log.d(TAG, "recu p");

                    if (p != null) {
                        try {
                            p.setSyncho(true);
                            // save remote id on obj
                            ObjDB.updateObj(p);

                            return Observable.empty();
                        } catch (Throwable th) {
                            ExceptionHandler.logException(th);
                            return Observable.error(th);
                        }
                    } else {
                        return Observable.empty();  // provisoirement si pb on renvoie vide
                    }
                })
                        .onErrorResumeNext(r -> {
                            Observable.empty();
                        })
                        .onExceptionResumeNext(error -> Observable.empty()) // go to next on error
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).onErrorReturn(error -> {
                    Log.d("ERROR", error.getMessage());
                    return 0;
                })

                        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
      })
     .subscribe(new DefaultSubscriber<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d(TAG, "on start");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "on next : " + t);
            }


            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                Log.e("XXX ERROR ", "" + t);
                patientSynchroInProgress = Boolean.FALSE;
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.e("XXX COMPLETE", "complete");
            }
        });
```

You are performing your retrofit call in `onNext(...)` so your network responses may not be sequential. By transforming your observable with the `map(...)` operator, each emission will become a separate network call. This allows your `onNext(...)` function to print sequential results from your retrofit calls and your `onComplete()` to execute when all subsequent calls are completed.

Comment: Thank you, I understand this method. But I have a problem with request(1), it is not recognized. What object do I apply it  to ?

Comment: @Nathalie what is your `request(1)` method?

Comment: request(1) is the flowable method to flow items one by one (http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Flowable.html)

Comment: @Nathalie my bad. You shouldn't need that method in this case. I've corrected my code

Comment: Thanks. And what about  .subscribe(new DefaultSubscriber<Integer>() {} ? It is not recognized either ?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `subscribe` from within an `onNext` or `map` is generally the wrong thing to do and indicates you should be using `flatMap` or `concatMap` in the upstream. In this case, `concatMap` can be used as it will only run one inner source, your retrofit call, and only do the next if this one completed.

```java
Flowable.fromIterable(objList)
.concatMap(item ->
     RetrofitHelper.createService(ObjService.class, true, authType, authToken)
     .createOrUpdateObj(item)
     .flatMap(p -> {
         if (p != null) {
             try {
                 p.setSyncho(true);
                 // save remote id on obj
                 ObjDB.updateObj(p);

                 return Observable.just(item);
             } catch (Throwable th) {
                 ExceptionHandler.logException(th);
                 return Observable.<Integer>error(th);
             }
         } else {
             return Observable.<Integer>empty();  // provisoirement si pb on renvoie vide
         }
     })
     .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<Integer>empty())
     .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
)
.subscribe(new DefaultSubscriber<Integer>() {
     @Override
     public void onStart() {
            Log.d(TAG, "on start");
     }

     @Override
     public void onNext(Integer t) {
         Log.d(TAG, "on next : " + t);
     }


     @Override
     public void onError(Throwable t) {
        Log.e("XXX ERROR ", "" + t);
        patientSynchroInProgress = Boolean.FALSE;
     }

     @Override
     public void onComplete() {
         Log.e("XXX COMPLETE", "complete");
     }
});
```

Comment: I am testing this, looks good except the subscribe (new DefaultSubscriber<Integer>()) is not recognized. What is the correct way to have the onComplete in this case ?

Comment: How is it not recognized?

Comment: You are probably getting type mismatch because the lambda didn't infer its return type correctly. I've updated the example.